# Does 'git status' exist in GitHub Desktop?

Tags: git, github-desktop

GitHub Desktop's `Sync` button — which displays what it determines to be the most relevant action, usually `Fetch origin`, `Push origin`, or `Pull origin` — doesn't give a lot of detail about what you might be pushing or pulling.

Is there a way to do the equivalent of `git status`, but from GitHub Desktop? This way, a user could see what they would be pulling down before they do so. And they'd be able to adjust their local project or otherwise delay pulling.

Comment: Fetch doesn’t pull?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No. Fetch and pull both download any new changes, but pull actually integrates them with your local copies. See https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/difference-between-git-fetch-git-pull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git status` will only let you know how many commits ahead or behind your local branch is, compared to `origin/master`. GitHub Desktop already displays that information in the `Sync` button with a small number next to `Push origin` or `Pull origin`.

Only a filtered `git log` would have detail about *what* changed.

A GitHub Support representative mentioned an ongoing effort for branch comparisons in GitHub Desktop tracked here: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3956. This is the closest thing that would allow users to see change details before pushing or pulling.